# Does website latency consider browser processing?

Tags: wordpress, optimization, web

I'm using the Safari Timeline "Network Requests" to check latency.  There are three main areas of latency:

1. waiting for initial server response
2. getting the response/data
3. web browser processing/rendering the response

Does latency reported by Safari consider all the above or just 1 & 2?

Also, what would be a good latency for a default, fresh wordpress sample page (in ms) on a shared/cheap plan?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seeing part of this questions is Safari and Safari Dev Tools specific, you're probably better off at http://apple.stackexchange.com

But what is a "good latency for a default, fresh wordpress sample page" is really difficult to pin down, as it has to take into consideration the server and load, the network connection and your own ISP and location. And that's best asked at http://serverfault.com